# Listener pattern implementation

Tags: java, design-patterns, asynchronous

In my project, I am doing asynchronous processes in almost every classes. To explain my problem, I have created a sample:

```
public interface TestListener {
  void onResponse(Response result);
  void onError(Exception e);
}

public class AsyncTask {
  TestListener testListener;

  public AsyncTask(TestListener testListener, Request request)
  {

  }

  public void excute()
  {
    try {
      // process request
      Response response = new Response();
      testListener.onResponse(response);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      testListener.onError(e);
    }
  }
}

public class Test1 implements TestListener {

  public void doStuff()
  {
    Request request = new Request();
    // add some stuff to request;
    AsyncTask task = new AsyncTask(this, request);
    task.excute();
  }

  @Override
  public void onResponse(Response result)
  {
    // process response

  }

  @Override
  public void onError(Exception e)
  {
    // process error

  }
}

public class Test2 implements TestListener {

  void someStuff()
  {
    Request request = new Request();
    // add some stuff to request;
    AsyncTask task = new AsyncTask(this, request);
    task.excute();
  }

  @Override
  public void onResponse(Response result)
  {
    // process response

  }

  @Override
  public void onError(Exception e)
  {
    // process error

  }
}
```

This doesn't look good to me. In every class I have `onResponse` and `onError`. What I want to do is just create a helper class that will have `onResponse` and `onError` and it will return me the response.

```
public class Test1{
  public void doStuff(){
    AsyncHelper helper = AsyncHelper.getInstance();
    Response response = helper.test1Method(request);
  }
}
```

I have two questions:

1. Am I thinking correctly to remove `onResponse` code from every class and collect in one class.
2. How should I create an `AsyncHelper` class?

Comment: Is the functionality of Test1.onResponse the same as Test2.onResponse?

Comment: nope they are different.e.g test1 is login so I will get authentication response and test2 is profile so I will get user details in test2 response.

Comment: Then how would you want to extract them into a helper method? I mean, without cluttering up that Class?

Comment: So you'd like to call your tasks synchronously? What should happen in case of error?

Comment: @palacsint In case of success it will show progress bar and return return Response object. In case of error it will show error dialog and it will return null. I am starting this project so i want to make sure that which way to go. because after some time it hard switch the way.

Answer (score 4):

Naming the classes and the design (at least as far as I can see from the code you pasted) suggests that you want to use the **observer pattern**. The main idea of this pattern is to use listeners which implement common listener interface and register them for the specific object which you want to make '**observable**'. Then in the observable object you can call `notifyAllListeners()` method or `notifyAllListenersOnError()` or some similar which will do nothing else than for listener from registered listeners call `listener.notify()` (or `listener.onError()` etc.).

Methods `notify()`, `onError()` etc have to be declared in the common listener interface.

What I mean is described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

The main idea is:

1. Create observable object.
2. Create as many listeners which implements common listener interface.
3. Register all created listeners for the observable object.
4. In the observable object call `notifyAll` code.

[image]

I also created [a short article](http://codeblocker.blogspot.co.at/2012/11/human-nature-patterns-observer-pattern.html) which explains the idea.

Comment: [`notify`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify()) is probably a bad idea in Java.

Comment: above it is just a pseudo code. and the explanation of the observer pattern which can be implemented in many languages.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the `Observable` class and `Observer` interface in `java.util`. You can extend `Observable` without overriding any of its methods for most simple implementations.

[java.util.Observable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html)

[java.util.Observer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Observer.html)

.NET's version of these interfaces are a little different, but might provide some different ideas that could be implemented in Java pretty easily.

[MSDN: IObservable(T) Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd990377.aspx)

[MSDN: IObserver(T) Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783449.aspx)

The mechanics of how each operate are slightly different:

- In Java, a class extending `Observable` marks itself as changed and calls a single method to notify all `Observer`s when it's ready.
- In .NET, a class implementing `IObservable<T>` maintains its own list of `IObserver<T>`s, and iterates over this list when ready, calling the appropriate notification (Error, Next, or Finished). This is likely closer to what you want and could be implemented in Java rather easily.